# Why can't Haddock find link destinations without Cabal?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I am in the process of writing a Cabal-install replacement for compiling my own projects (available for peeks [on Github](https://github.com/lih/World) if you are curious), and have almost made it fully operational but for one detail : when generating documentation for separate packages, Haddock doesn't seem to be able to find the HTML destinations of other packages, even though it *does* read the interface files generated by said other packages.

Here is the call that my build system makes to Haddock, and its accompanying output :

```
haddock --read-interface=/usr/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/base.haddock --read-interface=/usr/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.0.0/ghc-prim.haddock --title=vector-0.10.9.1 --source-module=/home/murray/World/%{FILE} -o /home/murray/.world/doc -h --use-contents=/home/murray/.world/doc/index.html --use-index=/home/murray/.world/doc/doc-index.html --optghc=-hide-all-packages --optghc=-package-name --optghc=vector-0.10.9.1 --optghc=-package-id --optghc=world-main --optghc=-optP--include=.build/deps/macros.h --optghc=-I.build/pool --optghc=-i/home/murray/.world/obj --optghc=-package --optghc=base --optghc=-package --optghc=ghc-prim --optghc=-ipackages/vector/0.10.9.1/source --optghc=-XCPP --optghc=-XDeriveDataTypeable --read-interface=file:///home/murray/.world/doc,/home/murray/.world/doc/primitive-0.5.2.1.haddock --read-interface=file:///home/murray/.world/doc,/home/murray/.world/doc/deepseq-1.3.0.2.haddock --read-interface=file:///home/murray/.world/doc,/home/murray/.world/doc/array-0.5.0.0.haddock -D/home/murray/.world/doc/vector-0.10.9.1.haddock .build/pool/Data/Vector/Storable.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Generic.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Generic/Base.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Generic/Mutable.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Size.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Fusion/Util.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Monadic.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Internal/Check.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Generic/New.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Storable/Mutable.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Storable/Internal.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Mutable.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Unboxed.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Unboxed/Base.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Primitive.hs .build/pool/Data/Vector/Primitive/Mutable.hs

.build/pool/Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Size.hs:25:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `*'
    In the instance declaration for `Num Size'

.build/pool/Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Size.hs:25:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `abs'
    In the instance declaration for `Num Size'

.build/pool/Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Size.hs:25:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `signum'
    In the instance declaration for `Num Size'
Haddock coverage:
 100% (  5 /  5) in 'Data.Vector.Fusion.Util'
 100% (  6 /  6) in 'Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Size'
  11% (  1 /  9) in 'Data.Vector.Internal.Check'
  83% (104 /126) in 'Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic'
  85% ( 88 /104) in 'Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream'
  64% ( 42 / 66) in 'Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable'
 100% (  3 /  3) in 'Data.Vector.Generic.Base'
  76% ( 37 / 49) in 'Data.Vector.Mutable'
Warning: Couldn't find .haddock for export Data.Primitive.Types.Prim
  74% ( 37 / 50) in 'Data.Vector.Primitive.Mutable'
   5% (  1 / 20) in 'Data.Vector.Generic.New'
  25% (  1 /  4) in 'Data.Vector.Storable.Internal'
  79% ( 46 / 58) in 'Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable'
  93% (215 /232) in 'Data.Vector.Generic'
Warning: Data.Vector.Primitive: Instances of type and data families are not yet supported. Instances of the following families will be filtered out:
  Mutable
Warning: Couldn't find .haddock for export Data.Primitive.Types.Prim
  96% (184 /191) in 'Data.Vector.Primitive'
Warning: Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base: Instances of type and data families are not yet supported. Instances of the following families will be filtered out:
  Mutable, MVector, Vector
  17% (  1 /  6) in 'Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base'
  96% (201 /210) in 'Data.Vector.Unboxed'
Warning: Data.Vector.Storable: Instances of type and data families are not yet supported. Instances of the following families will be filtered out:
  Mutable
  97% (194 /200) in 'Data.Vector.Storable'
Warning: Data.Vector: Instances of type and data families are not yet supported. Instances of the following families will be filtered out:
  Mutable
  94% (199 /212) in 'Data.Vector'
Warning: Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Mutable: could not find link destinations for:
    Data.Primitive.Array.MutableArray Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Primitive.Mutable: could not find link destinations for:
    Data.Primitive.ByteArray.MutableByteArray Control.DeepSeq.NFData Data.Primitive.Types.Addr Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Generic.New: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.DeepSeq.NFData Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Generic: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Primitive: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.DeepSeq.NFData Data.Primitive.ByteArray.MutableByteArray Data.Primitive.Types.Addr Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Unboxed: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.DeepSeq.NFData Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector.Storable: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.DeepSeq.NFData Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
Warning: Data.Vector: could not find link destinations for:
    Control.DeepSeq.NFData Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
```

I also tried pretty much all possible ways to write the `--read-interface` flag, including :

- as a relative path to the build directory
- as a `file://` URL
- with 0, 1 and 2 prefixes that are supposed to indicate the HTML link directory

I know the interface files are being read correctly because Haddock fails when the files are absent, and I know that the HTML files are in the right place because I am browsing them right now, so I can't find an explanation for why Haddock doesn't see them.

This situation has been stumping me for almost two months, and I've learned to accept the greyness of a life without hyperlinks in my documentation, but if anyone knows what to do, I will be eternally grateful :-)

Thanks for your time,

Comment: perhaps this helps: http://documentup.com/feuerbach/standalone-haddock

Comment: Thank you for the link, but as I understand it, `standalone-haddock` needs the dependencies to be installed and I would like to be able generate documentation without having to install every package, if possible. Is it possible that Haddock requires packages to be installed to find links correctly ?

Comment: I am not sure. But why not take the obvious solution: if it works when packages are installed, then install the packages. (In a cabal sandbox if you're cautious.) Or do you mean you have a set of packages that is not cabal-install-able? Then it's doubtful whether haddock can process it. I think it needs to resolve (all) references the same way ghc would.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it works when packages are installed, since I have never tried it. The Haddock documentation didn't mention anything about packages, so I didn't try anything in that direction. Another reason I haven't considered that approach is that it would be long and arduous, since some of my packages are not cabal-powered and it would take some effort to craft the appropriate functions to make them appear so. Anyway, I gyess I have no choice in the matter, so I'd better get to it... Thanks again for your help, in any case :-)